# How to convert 1D to 2D by Matlab program

Tags: matlab

I would like to ask a question about Matlab program.

I have vector `a`

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12];
```

I would like to convert vector `a` to 2D array. Normally, I use this code to convert it.

```
m =1;
for i=1:4
   for j=1:3
      b(i,j) = a(m);
      m=m+1;
   end
end
```

Then `b` is a 2D matrix.

```
b =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
    10    11    12
```

Anybody, have an idea to convert 1D to 2D without using loop.

Thanks,

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check out the [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) function and help page.

In particular,

```
B = reshape(A,m,n)
```

returns the `m`-by-`n` matrix `B` whose elements are taken column-wise from `A`. An error results if `A` does not have `m*n` elements.

Note that it is column-wise, so I suggest you make a matrix with 3 rows and 4 columns and then tip it on its side (`A.'` will take the transpose of a matrix).