# How to read a C outputfile into Matlab

Tags: c++, c, matlab, file, io

I created a matrix that is 500x500 in C which is about 1MB if anyone wants to see --> (http://www.megafileupload.com/8mad/test) . I need to read it into Matlab so that I can visualise it with `imagesc` . It's supposed to be some math generated artwork and I am very curious to see what it looks like.

So far i tried this:

```
fid = fopen('test', 'r')
mydata = fread(fid, 'double')
```

but it doesn't really work.

On the other hand, If anyone could suggest a different way to write the file such that it's more Matlab friendly is much appreciated.

My file basically contains a matrix with 500x500 elements of `integer` type.

This is how i save it on C:

```
if(fwrite(img, sizeof(int), w*h, fp) != w*h)
    printf("File write error.");
    fclose(fp);
```

Comment: `mydata = fread(fid, 'double')` expects `double` not `int`. That must be the issue.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That was it, thank you very much! There is one more problem, it reads it as list, that is, 250000x1 .

Comment: check my updated answer.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yeah it worked just fine, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're creating a binary file containing integers. I assume those are 32 bit integers (you'd have to check that from the C side or use `stdint.h` and the `int32_t` type).

If you have 32 bit integers stored, you could read your matlab file just like you're doing but using the correct type:

```
mydata = fread(fid, 'int32')
```

else matlab will map your integer values 2 by 2 into doubles and you'll probably get 0 or NaN values.

Then you get a 1D array, to reshape your array into a 2D array, have a look at the `reshape` function. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125896/how-to-convert-1d-to-2d-by-matlab-program) for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following:

1. Open file `Test` for reading.
2. Read 500x500 elements of type `int32` into matrix `I`.
3. Close the file.
4. **Transpose matrix** `I` - because 2D arrays of C are [row major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order), and MATLAB matrices are column major, you need to transpose a matrix written within C and read in MATLAB.
5. Display the image using `imagesc`.

---

```
f = fopen('Test', 'r');
I = fread(f, [500, 500], 'int32');
fclose(f);
I = I';
imagesc(I);
```

[image]